# jQuery Fadein Not Working on Wordpress Localhost

Tags: jquery, wordpress, themes

I'll start by saying this site is not on a live server at all, it is being built locally by me to be deployed later. I'm not a jQuery person and am learning as I go, and was using an online solution for this.

The goal is to have an element fade in when a button is clicked. I followed a tutorial and it didn't work.

Some things to consider:
1. The parent theme is Divi
2. This is using a child theme (not sure how much that matters)
3. The button and the element to fade in are not in the same section

Here is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function($){
$("#goals-button").click(function(){
$("#goals-content").fadein(1000,"linear");
});
});
</script>
```

I have checked and double checked that the button and the section have the correct id tags, so I know that's not the problem.

I have put this code in the correct section as well. I just don't understand why it's not working. I even tried using the original tutorial code and that didn't work at all. Could this be an issue with jQuery running on local environments?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: **fadeIn** instead of **fadein**. I dont know if this resolve the problem.

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much, what a small thing to miss.

Answer (score 2):

I had `fadein` and not `fadeIn`, silly mistake.